# What if my Snorkel labeling function has a very low coverage over a development set?

Tags: labeling, snorkel

I am trying to label a span recognition dataset using Snorkel and am currently at the stage of improving labeling functions. One of the LF has a rather low coverage because it only labels a subclass of one of the entity spans. What would be the impact of low coverage labeling functions on the final downstream span recognition model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the labeling function is low coverage, it might have high empirical accuracy over the class it is labeling. According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrIkus844B4&ab_channel=MobilizeCenter) video on "Best Practices for Improving Your Labeling Functions" from Snorkel co-founder Paroma Verma, those Snorkel LF's that have low coverage but good empirical accuracy should not be discarded.